# Escaping special characters in java for calling sed

Tags: java, sed

In my Java application, I need to modify a remote properties file.
This file is accessed through SSH, and, for the moment, is modified by calling `sed` on the remote server.

My problem is that the properties file to modify contains items that are composed of special characters (such as passwords). These special characters need to be escaped so that the value of the property is modified properly.

My question is : is there a better way than escaping every single special character ? Is there a method that would escape all the special characters ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are, of course, many libraries for easing this process. Exactly which characters do you consider special? (Or, if easier, which set of characters is not special?).

Comment: I consider as special all characters like `/\&$_` etc. All these characters make my sed command misbehave. For all the characters like letters, digits or some symbols like `=()[]{}`, it is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to escape every single character that was a problem, using that piece of code :

```
// Replace backslashes first, as it is used for escaping
myVar = myVar.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("\\"), "\\\\\\\\");

// Then replace all the other special characters
myVar = myVar.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("/"), "\\\\/");
myVar = myVar.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("&"), "\\\\&");
myVar = myVar.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("$"), "\\\\\\$");
myVar = myVar.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("'"), "'\"'\"'");
```

Comment: Not working for me. Below is the sed command I want to run.    

sed -e '/HOST/ s/^#*/#/' -i /tmp/abcd.txt

Answer (score 0):

something like ?

```
MyString="[some*char+and.word\\with/cntrl]"
printf "%s""${MyString}" | sed 's|\\|\\&|g;s|[][*.?/]|\\&|g' | read -r MyString

# printf "%s\n" "${MyString}"
\[some\*char+and\.word\\with\/cntrl\]
```

Comment: I get `sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unknown option to 's'`

Comment: I tried `echo "${MyString}" | sed 's/\[*.\/+?]/\\&/g' | read -r MyString`, and it has no effect on my input string.

Comment: i adapt for using a printf to avoid interpretation by shell and modify the pattern

Comment: That won't do the trick. I still have troubles with the characters & or $ for example.
Many thanks however.

Comment: Yes not all the char are in &, $ and ^ should be put between the [] (after ?/ by example) and some more depending version of sed used